# What metaphor would best describe the relationship between 'Value' and 'Type'?

Tags: types, language-agnostic, glossary

I'm trying to draw comic explaining 'value' and 'type' accurately, and I'm having a major problem: The way people use the term "type" compared to "value" in sources everywhere is driving me mad. I keep reading definitions in various metaphors:

1. A 'type' is an empty shell of properties, and a 'value' is what fills it in.
2. A 'type' is a factory that 'values' are built from.
3. A 'type' is a blueprint of a factory that creates 'values'
4. A 'type' is a rulebook telling what a 'value' can do.
5. A 'type' is an identification label for a 'value' that already has innate properties built in.
6. A 'type' is a organization chamber that 'values' reside before they get summoned into a program.

Worse is I keep hearing "Type" used as the adjective "Typed," which confuses me even more: Isn't type a noun? Plus, it feels like there are multiple definitions and contexts going on whenever someone uses this term. I feel like it is impossible to explain what a 'type' is without people getting **really** nit-picky about the details.

I don't know where to really ask this question, but I've been reading for days on end to no reasonable answer. How I should visualize 'type', and how it relates to 'value'? And which of my 6 interpretations would people be the least nitpicky about? My head really hurts right now...

My comics would explain the concepts in Python, but depending on the answers, I could try to explain programming concepts in a language-neutral manner.

Answer (score 1):

A type is like a sports team and a value is like one of its players. The New York Knicks are just a logo, a jersey, a set of colors, a name. It takes a player to wear that jersey and represent that team to make the Knicks anything of value (pun). If the Knicks are a type, Patrick Ewing is one of its values.

Comment: So in other words, a Type is a brand that a Value belongs to? And does the type give the value its properties - or does the value already have properties, and the type just identifies them?

Comment: If you want to think of it in terms of brands, like Apple, BMW, Craftsman, types are more like the specific models, like the iPhone 7, 335i, cordless drill. A type in OOP (object-oriented programming) can be a single property, like an integer or a boolean (true/false), or a collection of properties, like a custom class that you made named `Dragon` that may have a string property for its name, an integer property for its age, etc. This metaphor works well because a BMW M4 is much more complex than a toothpick, but both are still types.

Comment: As for values, every physical BMW M4 you see on the road and every toothpick in the box is a value of their respective types. Henry has a car of type BMW M4, and that red one right there, that specific one, is the value. Values fill properties but the property determines what kind of value it will allow by defining what type it is. If there is only one property, then that is the type--like a toothpick or an integer. And if there are multiple properties, then that collection is the type--like a car or a class with multiple properties.

Comment: The BMW M4 is a good way to think of types because the M4 itself is a type and each unit produced by the BMW factory is a value of that type. But the M4 itself is made up of many other types, like tires, seats, cam shafts, catalytic converters, etc. Why is a catalytic converter a type? Because it's stamped out in factories and used in many other cars, of all types. The catalytic converter itself is also made up of many types, like a metal housing and a particulate filter. And if the converter needs two filters, like the M4 may require, you can say the converter's filter type has a value of 2.

Comment: What about integers and floats? They may be types, but the values within them look like they could differ quite a lot. Like, 1, 67, 34, etc fall under the integer type, but they look like different models of an integer to me, even if they fall under the same type branding. That's why I read your post as types being brands rather than models.

Comment: Also, don't fear my deep questions too much - Remember that I'm trying to draw comics that nail concepts like this down so no one has any more confusion of them.